# Invitation API don't have user group to add invited user group to

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

On azure AD b2b, when we are inviting user to use the application, we have possibility to add invited user to group. From what I see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory/b2b/customize-invitation-api the invitation API does not have such possibility. Is there anything we could do, to send invitation from our application and add invited user to concrete group during the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invitation API does not have such possibility. You need two steps to achieve this. You can integrate them into one behavior.

1.[send invitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

[image]

2.Get the user id from step1. Then [Add the invited user to a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

[image]